# How to configure a Serverless S3 bucket resource to use a CORS AllowOrigin set to the http endpoint of its function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm using [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) to create a web application that serves its static content, e.g. a web font, from a S3 bucket. The S3 bucket is configured as a resource in my *serverless.yml* file. Its CORS configuration has an *AllowOrigin* set to a wildcard.

I want to change this to have an *AllowOrigin* with the http endpoint of the service as created by Serverless, e.g. `31alib51b6.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.

I wondered if it's possible to configure this in the *serverless.yml* file itself.

My example *serverless.yml* file:

```
service: example-service

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs4.3
  region: eu-west-1

functions:
  web:
    handler: handler.handler
    name: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
    description: ${self:service} web application - ${self:provider.stage}
    events:
      - http:
        path: web
        method: get
      - http:
        path: web/{proxy+}
        method: get

resources:
  Resources:
    S3Assets:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties: 
        BucketName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-assets
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
            - AllowedMethods:
                - GET
                - HEAD
              AllowedOrigins:
                - "*"
```

Comment: How do you upload your assets to the S3? Are you doing automatically?

Comment: I do it separately from the serverless deploy, using the aws cli

Comment: Ahh.. So I need to describe new task in my package.json? It is not possible to do it via serverless?

Comment: I think it wasn't possible when I tried this. I simply added a `aws s3 sync` command to the deploy step in my package.json. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html for its documentation

Comment: Hey. I just finished work on serverless plugin for binary support: https://github.com/maciejtreder/serverless-apigw-binary  You can also take a look at angular-universal boilerplate on aws lambda + api gw boilerplate. Check it out here: https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-serverless

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define the AllowedOrigin with the following statement:

```
    CorsConfiguration:
      CorsRules:
        - AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
          AllowedOrigins:
            - Fn::Join:
              - ""
              - - "https://"
                - Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
                - ".execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
```

"Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi" references the internal name of the generated API.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot 

Comment: Incorrect type. Expected "string".yaml-schema: AWSS3BucketCorsRuleDefinition
Starting on Fn::Join: all the way to the end.